# Observer Pattern with events instead of parameters (Push-Model)

Tags: design-patterns, observer-pattern

Right now I am trying to fully understand the concept of the Observer Pattern.

To my understanding (correct me if I am wrong):
It is recommended to use events instead of parameters if you have different Observers who needs a different set of parameters and you dont want your updateFuntion to contain all the variables

=> unnecessary data transfer in the updateFunction

=> problems when updateFunction needs one more parameter (you have to change all the Observers)

Can you explain to me how using events will solve this problem and how this is implemented? (perhaps in Java?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose we have an observer interface defined with a method accepting a list of arguments, like this.

```java
interface Observer {
    void doObserve(String name, String value);
}
```

Then, suppose we have a few classes implementing that interface.

```java
class ObserverA implements Observer {
    @Override
    public void doObserve(String name, String value) {
    }
}

class ObserverB implements Observer {
    @Override
    public void doObserve(String name, String value) {
    }
}
```

Now suppose that over time, requirements have evolved, and some of the observers need to know about some additional information, such as a "description".  In order to implement this requirement, we have to go back to change the method signature defined in `Observer` and update all classes that implement the interface.

```java
interface Observer {
    void doObserve(String name, String value, String description);
}

class ObserverA implements Observer {
    @Override
    public void doObserve(String name, String value, String description) {
    }
}

class ObserverB implements Observer {
    @Override
    public void doObserve(String name, String value, String description) {
    }
}
```

If we instead group these arguments into an "event" object or "parameters" object, then we decouple the `Observer` interface from the concrete implementations in the classes.

```java
class ObserverEvent {
    String name;
    String value;
    // getters/setters omitted for brevity
}

interface Observer {
    void doObserve(ObserverEvent event);
}

class ObserverA implements Observer {
    @Override
    public void doObserve(ObserverEvent event) {
    }
}

class ObserverB implements Observer {
    @Override
    public void doObserve(ObserverEvent event) {
    }
}
```

Replaying that earlier scenario, if we have a new requirement for a description field, then we can simply add it to the `ObserverEvent` and optionally modify only the specific classes that care about using the description.

```java
class ObserverEvent {
    String name;
    String value;
    String description;
}
```

This is a much smaller code change.

In this example, neither of the code changes was significantly difficult.  In a very large codebase though with many implementations of `Observer`, decoupling the arguments from the interface's method signature like this can really simplify maintenance.  Routine code changes won't require editing so many files.  Method signatures won't explode into a list of so many arguments that it becomes difficult to read.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. But this doesn't solve the issue of unnecessary data transfer.
lets say ObserverA only needs one parameter, doObserve(String name), if we pass the ObserverEvent, ObserverA gets all the values ... Can be problematic if we have a lot of Observers and only some of them needs to deal with this certain Event

Comment: I don't think there is anything inherent to the observer pattern, or the use of an event class to encapsulate its arguments, that specifically addresses that.  If you really want to guarantee that some observers receive one set of arguments (and only those arguments) while other observers receives another set of arguments (and only those arguments), then that likely indicates a need for 2 different kinds of observer interfaces, using 2 different method signatures.

Comment: @Ayox, I'm glad to hear this helped.  If you'd like, you can mark this as the accepted answer without waiting for reputation.  As a bonus, you'll get +2 for yourself when you accept an answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation  I think that will be enough to bring you up to 15 reputation, which gains you the privilege to start upvoting questions and answers.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges    Welcome to the Stack Overflow community!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use 2 approaches that can be combined:

1) Use special context object to share data between observers and observable object. You can put data into context object, pass it to observers and let them change data in it. Being notified by observer observable object reads context and uses that data. For example, you have observer-patterns that do some job. After job is finished each of them notify observable object(s). Observable reads shared context which was injected into observers on constructors level and determine which resources is now available to start another job.

2) Use notification or event class that will be a param of Notify() method. This event object has EventParams property to be read by observable object. For example, when your observer raises progress event (ProgressEvent e) you read its e.EventArgs.Status and use as you need. You can make interface for ObserverEvent and for ObserverEventParams and make implementations of it for each kind of event. In your observable class you can still accept interfaces and then use Chain of responsibility pattern or something like this

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :) Is it possible to share an example? I dont really if I have understood it properly ;)

Comment: If you can't catch an idea, my example will not help ;) Teach yourself with basic patterns before use them. It is bad thing to use patterns without understand them